# How do you make Babel 7 understand import and export?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to hard to make babel-node understand import and export. I tried various Babel plugins and presets, but none of them seem to work, and even worse, I can't even tell if Babel is loading my .babelrc or not.

Here's my barebones setup using **Node 10.16**:

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "jssb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "[redacted]",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "whatever": "npx babel-node -- ./whatever"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7"
  }
}
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

### whatever (chmod a+x)

```
#!/usr/bin/env npx babel-node --

import path from 'path';

const main = () => {
  console.log(typeof path);
}

main();
```

Whenever I run `whatever`, I get the following (stacktrace shortened):

```
import path from 'path';
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

I tried running `whatever` four different ways, but I got the same result every time:

```
./whatever
npx babel-node -- ./whatever
npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env -- ./whatever
yarn whatever
```

Why? I thought preset-env was taking care of transpiling import and export. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need this plugin? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs

Comment: I tried it. Just now, I tried it again, added it with `yarn add -D` and added it under `plugins` in `.babelrc`. No change.

Comment: babel-node may not support ES-style module imports? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html#es6-style-module-loading-may-not-function-as-expected

Comment: It's true in the REPL, they're not supported. But I'm using other legacy Node projects using a similar setup, some with Babel 6, others with Babel 7, and import/export works just fine. The env config suggests those are transpiled by default, but yet they don't work for me: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules

Answer (score 0):

After talking on Slack with Logan Smyth, one of the main contributors to Babel, it turns out this doesn't work because the file I'm using doesn't have a .js extension.

Normally, node will treat any file passed to it as a .js file. Same was true in Babel 6 with babel-node.

But in Babel 7, filenames are validated against a list of extension, and not having .js will fail that check.

If I really want the filename without an extension with babel-node in Babel 7, I'll have to use `require()` instead of `import`. For example:

### whatever

```
#!/usr/bin/env npx babel-node --

const { default: answer } = require('./answer');

const main = () => {
  console.log(answer);
}

main();
```

### answer.js

```
export default 42;
```

When executing any of the following:

```
./whatever
npx babel-node -- ./whatever
npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env -- ./whatever
yarn whatever
```

I get:

```
42
```